# Sincronizar una tabla

Tags: delphi

Esta aplicación se ejecuta en una tablet, dentro de una red.
Tengo un Botón que agrega un registro a una tabla:

```
procedure TTurnosList.CornerButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
          with D_Turnos do
               begin
                    TurnosSocios.Insert;
                    TurnosSociosCod_Socio.Value := SociosCod_Socio.Value;
                    Cod_Socios_Esperando.Add(IntToStr(D_Turnos.SociosCod_Socio.Value));
                    TurnosSocios.Post;
                    TurnosSocios.ApplyUpdates();
                    TurnosSocios.CommitUpdates;
                    ConexionTurnos.Commit;
               end;
end;
```

Por otra parte, desde otras PC's pueden actualizar la misma tabla. Y con un `TIdTCPServer` tengo que actualizar la vista de dicha tabla, que lo hago a continuación

```
procedure TD_Turnos.Tablet_IdTCP_ServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var S: String;
begin
     S := AContext.Connection.Socket.ReadLn;
     if S <> ''
     then
          Begin
               TurnosSocios.Close;
               TurnosSocios.Open;
               TurnosList.Cod_Socios_Esperando.Delete(StrToInt(S));
          End;
end;
```

La pregunta es ¿Cómo los sincronizo para evitar conflictos?.

Comment: En primer lugar, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Sobre tu pregunta, ¿Qué tipo de conflictos son los que estás teniendo o buscas evitar?

Comment: Bienvenido. 
Estaría bien que comentaras qué componentes estás usando para conectar y a qué Base de Datos.
Ten en cuenta también si en la aplicación de los PC's puedes utilizar cursores de sólo-lectura.